# what is the structure of a for loop that will output the contents of a multidimensional array in c++

Tags: c++

I need to see an example of how one would go about outputting a multidimensional array.

```
string** row = new string*[level];
for(int i = 0; i < level; ++i) {
      row[i] = new string[level];
}

// outputting:

int x; // filled with some value

int y; // filled with some value
```

How would I print `row[y][x]` by going through `y` then `x`?

Comment: Nested `for` loops, one for `x` and one for `y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should maybe consider using std::vector instead of manual dynamic allocation since you are using C++:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> rows(level);
```

instead of

```
string** row = new string*[level];
```

and initialize it this way:

```
for (std::vector<std::string>& row_vec : rows)
{
    row_vec.resize(level);
}
```

and to iterate over it just use nested for loops:

```
for (uint32_t x(0); x < level; ++x)
{
    for (uint32_t y(0); y < level; ++y)
    {
        std::cout << "rows[" << x << "][" << y << "] = " << rows[x][y] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: also can you push back a value to a specific spot in a vector